# Is there a tool for Splunk like Toad that allows for multiple queries in the same editor?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the standard Splunk query web interface that allows the user to enter a single query at a time that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a tool that allows multiple queries in the same editor that can be selected one at a time and queried so that as I'm working I can write a series of queries and execute them one at a time by selecting a single query?

Answer (score 2):

You can save your searches into Reports (or Alerts, or Dashboards)

And you can save searches into an *external* location (eg a text file), and copy-paste them when you want them again later

Or you could have complex searches that utilize `multisearch`, `append`, subsearches, etc

But otherwise, no - there is no way to create a "library" of searches, and then pick them from a list

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I hoping for ;) Oh well.

Comment: @John - it might be an interesting add-on to write ... or feature request to submit :)

Comment: I know, right :) There are a couple of Splunk JDBC drivers out there.  Might be a fun school project.  (https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/4794/, http://unityjdbc.com/splunk/splunk_jdbc.php)